# Apply Function to DataFrame with Unknown Number of Columns

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I have many pandas dataframes that have a different number of columns and column names, but which contain similar data (1s and 0s). I want to apply a function that works on all these dataframes.

Here's a simple example:

**Build dataframe:**

```
data = {'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6], 'C':[7,8,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Define function:**

```
def my_fn(a, b, c):
ans = a * b * c
return ans
```

**Apply function to dataframe:**

```
df.apply(lambda x: my_fn(x.A, x.B, x.C), axis=1)
```

**Question:** this works, of course, but what if the next dataframe has 5 columns (A,B,C,D,E)? My function should then be my_fn(a, b, c, d, e). I have potentially 1000s of dataframes to process like this, with differing numbers of columns.

**My Attempt Using Exec():**

```
my_cols = list(df.columns)
my_cols = ['x.' + item for item in my_cols]
args_str = ', '.join(my_cols)   #This gives--> 'x.A, x.B, x.C, x.D, x.E'
df.apply(lambda x: exec(my_fn(args_str)), axis=1)
```

**Result:** TypeError: my_fn() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'b', 'c', 'd' and 'e'

**Further Thoughts:**
I read other similar posts and using a dictionary was suggested, but these problems were sufficiently different, in my view. Maybe I'm approaching the problem completely the wrong way (very likely). Or maybe there's a simple solution that I haven't thought of (even more likely). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically answered the question yourself.

```
df.apply(lambda x: my_fn(x.A, x.B, x.C), axis=1)
```

Here you're using a lambda function with argument `x`, which represents a row. You even access the different columns (`x.A x.B x.C`). This means all the values you need are already stored inside `x`, thus `x` is an iterable. In fact, it's a pandas Series object.

There is no need to split `x` into different values to pass them to another function. Put your logic directly into the function which you pass to `apply`.

```
def my_func(row):
    for col in row:
        # do something with col value
    return # some result

df.apply(my_func, axis=1)
```

The loop doesn't care about how many columns are in the dataframe, it will just process how many it's passed.

If you want to apply some kind of numerical calculation to `x`. You can also use numpy, eg. your example of multiplying all the columns together by row:

```
import numpy as np

def my_func(row):
    return np.product(row)

df.apply(my_func, axis=1)
```

Or as a lambda function:

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.product(x), axis=1)
```

You can also check the `apply` documentation for more information on how the method works:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and well described solution, sarrysyst. The solution works, and I also now have a better understanding of the apply method.